# Keras NLP TransformerDecoder MultiHeadAttention Value Error

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, transformer, attention-mechanism

Recently I have been working on a MIDI Music Generator using the TransformerEncoder & TransformerDecoder layers found in the Keras NLP library. There is not much info/help on these layers which is why I am here. Everything was fine until eventually needed to batch my input dataset to get around GPU memory limitations. Now I encountered this error:

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: tf__call)

Exception encountered when calling layer "multi_head_attention" " f"(type MultiHeadAttention).

dim -7 not in the interval [-4, 3]. for '{{node TransDecPitch/multi_head_attention/ExpandDims}} = ExpandDims[T=DT_INT32, Tdim=DT_INT32](TransDecPitch/Tile, TransDecPitch/multi_head_attention/ExpandDims/dim)' with input shapes: [?,64,64], [] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <-7>.

Call arguments received by layer "multi_head_attention" "                 f"(type MultiHeadAttention):
  • query=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 64, 562, 149, 1007), dtype=float32)
  • value=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 64, 562, 149, 1007), dtype=float32)
  • key=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 64, 562, 149, 1007), dtype=float32)
  • attention_mask=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 64, 64), dtype=int32)
  • return_attention_scores=False
  • training=False
  • use_causal_mask=False
```

To clarify some of the numbers above:

- Batch Size = 64
- Sequences Per Batch = 562
- Sequence Length = 149
- Embedding Layer Output Dim = 1007

This is the model architecture. I cannot paste the model summary because the error occurs befor reaching that line.

```
PITCH_INPUT_NODES = len(self.unique_x_pitch) # Actual value of this is 1006
PITCH_OUTPUT_NODES = len(self.unique_y_pitch) # Actual value of this is 1006 
PITCH_OUTPUT_DIM = PITCH_OUTPUT_NODES +1  # Actual value of this is 1007
PITCH_ATTENTION = 6 
TRANS_DROPOUT = 0.4
            
opt_pitch = Adam(1e-4)
            
input_pitch = Input(self.pitch_input_shape)
x_pitch = TokenAndPositionEmbedding(PITCH_INPUT_NODES,self.seq_length,PITCH_OUTPUT_DIM, name='EmbeddingsPitch')(input_pitch)
x_pitch = TransformerEncoder(PITCH_OUTPUT_NODES, PITCH_ATTENTION, TRANS_DROPOUT, name='TransEncPitch')(x_pitch)
x_pitch = TransformerDecoder(PITCH_OUTPUT_NODES, PITCH_ATTENTION, TRANS_DROPOUT, name='TransDecPitch')(x_pitch)
pitch_output = Dense(PITCH_OUTPUT_NODES, activation='softmax', name='OutputPitch')(x_pitch) #Pitch Output Layer
self.model_pitch = Model(input_pitch, pitch_output, name="ModelPitch")
self.model_pitch.compile(opt_pitch, tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
                                     metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()]
                                     )
```

Any help would be fantastic and please let me know if any helpers need more info.
Thank you

Comment: Seems to be a wrong parameter in the multihead attention. Which tensor refers to this value? input[1] = <-7>

Comment: Did you find a solution?